# Place Circular ImageViews on another in a row

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best approach to create a symmetry of circular images over each other same like shown below.

[image]

Any library or any custom widget? Or just we can do this with ConstraintLayout?

Comment: can you try https://github.com/KartikPrajapati/StackImageView?

Answer (score -1):

with [this](https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView) library you can make a circle view

[image]

```
<com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.CircleView
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"

    android:elevation="4dp"
    app:shape_circle_borderColor="@android:color/black"
    app:shape_circle_borderWidth="2dp">

        <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

 </com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.CircleView>
```

**Secend Step**
add all circle views in a linear Layout and set negative margin to below viwes for Example i Use image view

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What you're trying to say is completely irrelevant from the question.